# Determine if a function belongs to the sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and not to $L^q(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I don't understand the first conclusion of the user Tomas in the exercise

[Properties of function $f(x) = (1 + x^2)^{-\alpha/2}(\log(2+x^2))^{-1},\text{ }x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < \alpha < 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663172/properties-of-function-fx-1-x2-alpha-2-log2x2-1-text-x)

Why does the inequality 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+x^2)^{-\alpha q/2}(\log (2+x^2))^{-q}\ge \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+x^2)^{-\alpha q/2}(2+x^2)^{-qt}.  $$

lead us to conclude that if $q\in [1,1/\alpha)$ then $f\notin L^q(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks

Comment: Because asymptotically this is $x^{-q (\alpha + 2t)}$, which is integrable only when $q > 1 / (\alpha + 2t)$. Send $t$ to zero.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thanks a lot.